# How to restore content in the same Activity based on the calling Intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, restore

here's my scenario: I start an Activity A via an AppWidget. The AppWidget displays (inter alia) 3 buttons. Each of them has its own intent. They are designed to provide information to the Activity via a class called AppWidgetReceiver. In latter I create an intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, CreateNoteActivity.class);  
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
i.putExtra(AppWidget.WIDGET_ITS_TRIGGER_ID, trigger_id);  
i.putExtra(AppWidget.WIDGET_TITLE, title);  
i.putExtra(AppWidget.WIDGET_DESCRIPTION, descr);  
context.startActivity(i);
```

This launches the Activity A. Based on `trigger_id`, `title` and `descr` I create some sort of information menu for the user:

```
coreQuestionTitle   = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppWidget.WIDGET_TITLE);  
coreQuestionDescr   = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppWidget.WIDGET_DESCRIPTION);  
coreQuestionId      = getIntent().getIntExtra(AppWidget.WIDGET_ITS_TRIGGER_ID, -1); 
TextView tvCoreQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create_note_core_question_text);
tvCoreQuestion.setText(coreQuestionTitle);
```

All of this works fine. The problem arises when I don't 'close' the Activity via `this.finish()`, e.g. the home- or back-button is pressed. When I now click on an OTHER button on the AppWidget the previously opened Activity is restored instead of restarted. The `onCreate()` is not called. Instead, it jumps right into `onStart()`. I know that this is intended by the Activity lifecycle since the task is still alive.
Unfortunately, I really need to be able to retrieve the parameters specified in the intent to set the desired information. Moreover, I would like to be able to restore the state of ANY of 3 different tasks. Can anyone help me out on this?

By the way: I'm avoiding to pass the `onCreate()` by making use of android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" and `onConfigurationChanged()`. The declaration of the Activity in the Manifest.xml looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".notes.CreateNoteActivity"  
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  
    android:label="@string/create_note"  
    android:launchMode="singleTask"  
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >  
    <intent-filter>  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_HOME" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

Thanks in advance,
Steff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about specifically killing the Activity (by calling `this.finish()`) on your `onStop()` or `onPause()` methods? This may create extra overhead as the users click on the different buttons of your widget but is the only way you can force `onCreate()` to be called each click.

Comment: I've been thinking about that. What do recommend on how to persist the data for each different kind of 'entry' (i.e. the AppWidget Buttons)? Creating a dedicated SQLite-Table?

Comment: Persisting to SQLite would probably be worse than recreating your activity since at that point you're doing I/O. Think about use cases, if your users would not be doing a lot of back and forth to click the different buttons then recreating the class sounds OK. Also, if you keep your activity class tiny (not a lot of views or objects), recreating it will not be that bad either. On the other hand, I'd Look at Preferences files too, a lot less overhead than SQLite and perfect to persist simple data: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Since I'll only store very few items in the db I decide to go with it. Performance is not (truly) criticial in my app so this works out fine for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: Now here's one more thing. Almost everything is working as desired. The only problem remains if one presses the home-button. I don't stand a chance to intercept its behaviour. So how can I call this.finish() if the home button is pressed?

Comment: When that happens I believe android will cal onPause() or onStop() on your activity, so just override those and call finish() inside them.